# Как связать селект с чекбоксом?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Требуется связать чекбокс с мультиселектом. Изначально чекбокс активен, но при выборе из селекта, нужно, что бы чекбокс снимался, а если убрать всё из селекта, возвращался обратно. Какие есть варианты с использованием jQuery?

```html
<select multiple>
                <option>Чебурашка</option>
                <option>Крокодил Гена</option>
                <option>Шапокляк</option>
                <option>Крыса Лариса</option>
        </select>
        <input type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('select').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
});

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
  if($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(this).parent().find('select option:selected').prop("selected", false);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <select multiple>
    <option>Чебурашка</option>
    <option>Крокодил Гена</option>
    <option>Шапокляк</option>
    <option>Крыса Лариса</option>
  </select>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <select multiple>
    <option>Чебурашка</option>
    <option>Крокодил Гена</option>
    <option>Шапокляк</option>
    <option>Крыса Лариса</option>
  </select>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, но есть проблемка, таких мультиселектов несколько, поэтому нужно определять объекты по id, подскажите?

Comment: всё зависит от реализации. Сгруппированы ли они в какие-то блоки?

Comment: Да, все селекты находятся в одной форме, так же есть стандартные классы bootstrap

Comment: "а если убрать всё из селекта, возвращался обратно." - этот пункт из вопроса не реализован же.

Comment: @Speller так при выборе чекбокса связанный с ним селект очищается от выбранных значений. Это как при использовании групп radio - возможен только один вариант. Т.е. выбранным всегда будет либо чекбокс, либо селект.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  if ($("select option:selected").length > 0) {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
  } else {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple>
  <option>Чебурашка</option>
  <option>Крокодил Гена</option>
  <option>Шапокляк</option>
  <option>Крыса Лариса</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```